# Java - First letter of every word in a string

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program to assist in memorizing long paragraphs of text, and I am stuck. I am trying to write a method that, when passed a string, will return a string that contains just the first letters of the words in the string, plus newlines and punctuation. Any help?

Example:

This is a test sentence, that has a newline\n and some punctuation.

T i a t s, t h a n

a s p.

Comment: What are you currently struggling with? Got any code you need help with?

Comment: Give an example and post what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a regex you can simply use (if you don't expect accented letters):

```
String s = "a long sentence.\nWith a new line, and some punctuation!";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\w)\\w+", "$1"));
```

which outputs:

```
a l s.
W a n l, a s p!
```

Explanation:

- `\\w` represents a character in `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` => this won't work with accented letters
- `(\\w)\\w+` looks for a group of at least two letters
- `$1` returns the first capturing group (the part within parenthesis, i.e. the first letter).

Comment: Does this work with contractions? (I do not know how they are supposed to be handled but if the input is `Don't` does this produce `D 't`)?

Comment: @clcto I don't know if it works in the sense that I don't know what the op would expect in such a case. But yes, `Don't` would return `D't`.